# Xcodebuild set push messages capability by command line

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

I'm generating am IPA file using xcodebuild and I'm facing a big issue when I try to enable the capabilities. The specific one I need to enable is the push messages one.

Actually, I'm generating the xcodeproj from a crossplatform framework (FUSE) but it doesn't handle the capabilities well. This is why I need a way to do it in the compilation time by command line in order to automate the release process.

Comment: Capabilities are not added by xcodebuild they come from you entitlement file. I am not sure why using a FUSE filesystem would make a difference, but can you check if it's using the correct entitlements file? Be aware that xcodebuild uses the release configuration by default.

Comment: FUSE has a problem with the entitlements/capabilities. It activates the capability but the entitlement is never created. I made the trick by usign Xcode to enable the capabilty and I found the file where the entitlements are saved. One script will do the rest.

Comment: As mentioned by @ThomasBartelmess entitlement file you need to create by yourself without xcodebuild, and add your capabilities there. don't forget to add those capabilities in your app id.